# Выделить цветом отдельный Item в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть некоторый контейнер `ListView` для отображения строк:

```
<ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding AdressCount}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Adress}"/>
                <Run Text=" : "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Count}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Класс, колекции AdressCount :

```
public ObservableCollection<UrlCount> AdressCount { get; set; }
public class UrlCount
{
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Нужно выделить строку с наибольшим числом, или вернее с наибольшим значением `Count`,  красным цветом. Как это реализовать ?

**UPD.
UPD.**

Использовал `ItemContainerStyle` что бы менять стиль `Item`-а чье значение равно наибольшему вот так :

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
       <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMax}" Value="true">
             <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
           </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Однако, связать cо свойством внутри вьюхи не получается :

```
 public int MaxTagCount => URLsCount.Max(tag => tag.Count);
 public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
 public bool IsMax  => CurrentCount == MaxTagCount;
```

Свойство `CurrentCount` меняется каждый раз при добавлении нового обьекта в листвью.

Comment: А коллекция `URLsCount` периодически обновляется или создается один раз? А `Count` внутри `UrlCount` может меняться или он создается один раз?

Comment: @АндрейNOP `URLsCount` может меняться, как и `Count`.

Comment: Я не вижу способа сделать это без вынесения отдельного свойства с макс. значением в VM, но все осложняется тем, что вам придется отслеживать все изменения внутри `URLsCount` и внутри каждого `UrlCount`, который лежит в этой коллекции

Comment: Если есть возможность сделать `UrlCount` неизменяемым, то было бы всё гораздо проще. Т.е. вместо изменения `Count` вы создаете новый объект `UrlCount` с новыми значениями свойств и подменяете его в коллекции. Конечно, такой возможности у вас может и не быть...

Comment: @АндрейNOP а почему не очистить `ObservableCollection` и не заполнить новыми значениями при получении новых адресов ?

Comment: Можно и так. Тогда просто добавляете свойство в VM `MaxCount => AdressCount.Max(u => u.Count);`, затем в конструкторе VM добавляете подписку `AdressCount.CollectionChanged += (o, e) => NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MaxCount));` и в View вешаете дататриггер типа `если Count равен MaxCount установить Background = Red`

Comment: @АндрейNOP в принципе я вас понял. Можете написать ответ, что бы я его принял ?

Comment: У вас получилось реализовать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP увы нет, принцип понял а реализовать тригер не получается. остальное пока не трогаю. хочу просто выделить тот ListViewItem у которого `Count` =  определенному числу.

Comment: Хорошо, завтра попробую написать ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я набросал такой пример, мой Item (он неизменяемый, это важно, если этот класс будет изменяемый, то будет куча проблем - он должен будет реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, мы должны будем подписаться на событие `PropertyChanged` каждого экземпляра и не забыть вовремя отписаться, иначе будут утечки памяти):

```
class Item
{
    public int Value { get; }
    public Item(int value) => Value = value;
}
```

Теперь главная VM, ничего сложного, коллекция элементов, команда для их добавления и вычисляемое свойство с максимальным значением:

```
class MainVm : Vm
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
    public int MaxItem => Items.Max(i => i.Value);
    public DelegateCommand AddItem { get; }
    Random random = new Random();

    public MainVm()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        Items.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MaxItem));
        AddItem = new DelegateCommand(_ => Items.Add(new Item(random.Next(0, 10))));
    }
}
```

При изменении коллекции мы должны оповестить GUI, что максимальный элемент изменился (возможно) и его нужно перечитать.

Разметка окна:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0"
            Content="Click me" Command="{Binding AddItem}"/>
</Grid>
```

Теперь цвет фона максимального элемента. Хотелось бы, конечно, воспользоваться триггером, но у `DataTrigger` свойство `Value` не является свойством зависимости, поэтому привязка на нем не поддерживается. Остается только использовать конвертер.

У меня есть такая база для мультиконвертера, сравнивающего 2 объекта:

```
class ObjectsEqualConverter<T> : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public T EqualValue { get; set; }
    public T NotEqualValue { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type tt, object p, CultureInfo ci)
        => values[0].Equals(values[1]) ? EqualValue : NotEqualValue;
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] tt, object p, CultureInfo ci)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => this;
}
```

Я наследую от него конвертер в кисть:

```
class BrushEqualConverter : ObjectsEqualConverter<Brush> { }
```

Теперь можно им воспользоваться:

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{c:BrushEqualConverter EqualValue=Red, NotEqualValue=Transparent}">
                            <Binding Path="Value"/>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"
                                     Path="DataContext.MaxItem"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

`c` - это пространство имен, в котором лежит конвертер, типа такого: `xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfTest"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется я нашел более простое решение, за счет добавление нового булевского свойства в VM только почему то триггер не срабатывает когда IsMax = true. не могли бы взглянуть на UPD

Comment: Не, вы делаете что-то странное. У вас у каждого ListBoxItem будет установлен свой DataContext, т.е свойство IsMax должно быть в `UrlCount`, что в итоге усложнит решение ещё сильнее. Мой вариант проще будет. Если же вы хотите оставить IsMax в главной VM, то это свойство должно меняться каждый раз, когда GUI пробегает по элементам внутри списка, а это сделать невозможно

Comment: Спасибо, за рабочее решение. Правда `ObjectsEqualConverter` совсем не понятен, но думаю разберусь.

Comment: Он получает два объекта и просто сравнивает их, если они равны - возвращает одно значение, иначе - другое